# getting value from two dimensional array in wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am using a two dimensional array for inputting value from custom field. like this

```
  <input type="text" name="education[0][edu_title]" placeholder="Title">
  <input type="date" name="education[0][edu_to]" placeholder="To" class="calendar">
```

It is a loop that is value of 0 is changed to 1 and so on.
Now if the form is submitted i want to get each value.

```
  $tableedu = $wpdb->prefix . 'apply_edu';
    $education=$pst_data['education'];
    $sqldataedu = array();
    $count=0;
    foreach($education as $edu){
        $sqldataedu['edu_title'] = stripslashes($edu[$count]['edu_title']);
        $sqldataedu['edu_from'] = stripslashes($edu[$count]['edu_from']);
        $sqldataedu['edu_to'] = stripslashes($edu[$count]['edu_to']);
        $sqldataedu['edu_institute'] = stripslashes($edu[$count]['edu_institute']);
        $sqldataedu['apply_id'] = $lastid;
        $wpdb->insert($tableedu, $sqldataedu);
        $count++;
        }
```

how can i store each value in database

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? Are you looking to populate the fetched values into textfield?

Comment: I want to store the textfield value into database. @DebakantMohanty

Comment: Perhaps add this info in your question?

Comment: i have added @rbaleksandar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this save data in database.

```
$education = $_POST['education'];
foreach( $education as $arr ){
  $insert_data= array();
  $insert_data['edu_title'] = stripslashes($arr['edu_title']);
  $insert_data['edu_from'] = stripslashes($arr['edu_from']);
  $insert_data['edu_to'] = stripslashes($arr['edu_to']);
  $insert_data['edu_institute'] = stripslashes($arr['edu_institute']);
  $insert_data['apply_id'] = $lastid;
  $wpdb->insert($tableedu, $insert_data);

}
```

Comment: you can check before insert what is data show in array.
print_r($insert_data);

Comment: $wpdb->show_errors(); 
$wpdb->insert($tableedu, $insert_data);

Comment: $education is two dimensional array. education[0][edu_title]. how can i get the value that is present on for example this index education[3][edu_title] then

Comment: what should be in this case @userr5200704

Comment: This is also perfect you can get through $education[$counter]['edu_title'].
But what is issue in answer because it also gives value ?

Comment: it does not give the exact. i will check it again

Comment: stripslashes($edu[$count]['edu_title']); i have mention this in question. this does not works

Comment: replace $edu instead $education